# Distributing code to multiple locations

Tags: php, batch-file, web-applications, windows-server-2008

bit of a theory questions leading to possibly a bit more practical. I currently have a web application developed using PHP within a codeigniter framework.

The application is now in use by 5 separate customers each with their own specific amendments that extend the base/core code I have created. I'm now at the time that whenever I make any updates to the development version I am having to painstakingly hand copy each of the separate files/directories to each customer.

I'd like a bit input on how best to automate this process. The scenario is that the applications are running on a windows server with php 5.4 connecting to a mysql database. All domains/applications including the dev version are on the same server and use the same IP Address.

Would I be correct in thinking a batch file would be the best way to do this, if so can someone point me in the right direction for creating a batch file. Other thoughts I've had are possibly a download button on each site that starts the process of updating itself but again i'm not entirely sure how to go about this.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In don't know what you mean with `extend the base/core` exactly, but if the extensions are in separate files, you could share the core files via a php include directory. Then you only have one production version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how extensive your modifications are for the individual clients.  Is 90% shared code?  50%?

**If 90% of the code is common code:**
I would put my core codebase in one folder and then just use custom files for the modifications.

In the core code you need a way to tell the clients apart.  Let's assume you have a 'clientid' that is unique to the client.

**Example:**
Let's say we are in the core code and going to include a file called **user_admin.php** but this file is different for some of your clients but not all

```
function custominclude($file,$clientid){
    $customfile='/custom/'.$clientid.'/'.$file;
    if(file_exists($customfile)){
        include ($customfile); 
    }
    else{
        include ($file); 
    }
}
custominclude('user_admin.php',$clientid);
```

**EDIT based on your comment below.**

To sync two folders (or more) on a windows server.  Use a utility like GoodSync http://www.goodsync.com/  .  It lets you sync folders one way/both ways on the same machine or between different ones.  It should handle your task easily.  You can set it up to do it on a schedule or you can manually tell it you sync when you want.

Comment: Hi I appreciate the comments and sorry I wasn't quite clear enough. Without getting too in depth in the question and the reason behind it I'm essentially looking for the best method to copy files from one location to another on a Windows server in the most automated way possible. You both make valid points but without going too deeply into it they wouldn't work in this instance.

Comment: Good Sync looks perfect. Saves me writing unnecessary code. Thanks for your help!!!